# How to get data from questdb and get it in a js file?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, rest, codesandbox, questdb

**Description:**
Implement a ZoomingAndScrolling chart with infinite scrolling capability.

1. Set up a new project on CodeSandbox, using the template from the following link
   https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Charts/ZoomingAndScrolling/React/Light/
2. populate the chart by retrieving the data from the "trips" table using HTTP rest API from https://demo.questdb.io/. x should be "pickup_datetime" and y should be "trip_distance"
   https://questdb.io/docs/develop/query-data/#http-rest-api
3. provide infinite scroll functionality for the graph chart; the concept of infinite refers to the ability to dynamically load new data as needed than loading all the data at once. Reference:
   https://js.devexpress.com/Demos/WidgetsGallery/Demo/Charts/LoadDataOnDemand/React/Light/

Once you complete the task, please share the CodeSandbox link.

Not able to go ahead before fetching data from that table in questDB.

Comment: Instead of copying-pasting your homework, show us what you've already tried

Comment: Just started the codesandbox; want to get that data from questdb!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I actually was able to provide an answer based on the question. It seems the problem is fetching the data from the QuestDB public demo instance and I already replied

Answer (score 1):

I get this is an exercise about React, but I can help with the QuestDB side of things, which is blocking you :)

To get data from QuestDB in your example you should use [the exec endpoint of the REST API](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/api/rest/#exec---execute-queries).

Note that in the demo machine, the exec port is directly the 443 port, so you could execute this call to get the first 100 results

```
curl -G \                                                                            
  --data-urlencode "query=SELECT pickup_datetime, trip_distance from trips;" \
  --data-urlencode "limit=1,100" \
  https://demo.questdb.io/exec
```

As you can see, you can just issue queries changing the limit (next one would be from 101 to 200) until you get no results. You can choose a limit as high as you want for every page of data, so you probably want to adjust for how much data you want to display at once. Please be advised the demo is limited to 1000000 results per page.

If you want to see some javascript to help you, you can see an example at https://questdb.io/docs/develop/query-data/#querying-data.  Please note you would need to add the http `limit` parameter for pagination